# (De)Modulation of albedo

Tags: graphics, signal-processing, imaging

I've come across the term "demodulation" in various papers in the context of

"[...] demodulating (the) albedo [...]"

In this paper: "Spatiotemporal Variance-Guided Filtering" by Schied et al. and

"Interactive Reconstruction of Monte Carlo Image Sequences using a
Recurrent Denoising Autoencoder" et al." by Chaitanya et al.

After having a look at modulation I have a rough idea what it is, but I fail to see the application of signal (de)modulation in computer graphics.

---

**My question is:**
Can someone explain to me what is meant with "albedo modulation" ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't look at the papers, but here is what my intuition tells me: The albedo is a surface's intrinsic color. The color that you observe when looking at the surface is not that albedo but depends on various factors such as lighting and the camera position. De-modulation would then refer to calculating the actual albedo from an observed color.

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean removing the texture (albedo) color from the path traced image, based on rasterized g-buffer, before they start processing the image (estimating image variance, filtering and image reconstruction). This allows them to focus on light transport and luminance, rather then detecting noise and edges coming from texture details. And once the filtered image is reconstructed, they restore the albedo color.